# Modal transition shows view behind while transitioning

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, uimodaltransitionstyle

I have a `UITableView` controller with a plus button in the navigation bar. When `+` is pressed, a modal transition is triggered and a `UIView` is now presented. Problem is while the modal transtion is happening, I can see the `tableView` behind until the whole transition is done. This is a pretty jarring animation and does not look good at all. I have set the alpha value for the background color of both views at 0.7. Maybe this is causing the issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set alpha back to 1

Comment: @Azat but surely if we can set the alpha lower than 1 there must be a solution to this problem.

Comment: When you set alpha < 1 you get transparency, and you got it. If you don't want transparency, set alpha to 1. Am I right?

Comment: @Azat but it is only transparent during the animation, and goes back to normal after the animation.

Comment: It is because iOS don't show all controllers at same time, it removes them when not visible, there is dark background indicating that there is nothing anymore. Did you notice the `viewDidAppear:`, `viewDidDisapper:` callbacks? Their's purpose to inform about that

Answer (score 0):

When you present you modal view, you have a completion block:

```
func presentViewController(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                 animated flag: Bool,
               completion completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

Set you view transparency to 1.0 initially and set it to 0.7 in the completion block after the animation has ended.

Comment: Do I put this function in the class that controls the table view or the view that is presented with the modal transition?

Comment: It should be in the function that is called when you touch the + button.